# Install Third-party Python Modules in QGIS (Windows)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

i try to follow [this](https://umar-yusuf.blogspot.gr/2016/07/How-to-Install-Third-party-Python-Modules-in-QGIS-Windows.html) to Install Third-party Python Modules in QGIS (Windows).my QGIS version is the latest 2.18.10.

steps :

1. donwload ez_setup.py

2.copy paste at C:\Windows\System32

3.OSGeo4W shell Run as Administrator

4.python ez_setup.py

and i take that message :

[image]

any idea why ?

if i try to :

[image: im2]

Comment: The guide you used mentioned using ```pip``` to manage Python modules. When you run the OSGeo4W shell can type ```pip``` at the prompt?  The [latest list](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/x86_64/versions.html) of packages in the OSGeo4W installer includes pip.  You should be able to use that to install extra modules.

Comment: You only need to run (as Administrator): `python ez_setup.py -U setuptools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to run (as Administrator):

```
python ez_setup.py -U setuptools
```

Now, it will work perfectly; as it can be observed at next image for installing **pysal** python module (as in your reference) with:

```
easy_install pysal
```

[image]

Loading same module in QGIS:

[image]